# Make virtual environment setup faster

Tags: python, jenkins, continuous-integration, virtualenv

I have some automated tests on Jenkins where part of the build steps is to setup a virtual environment (Virtualenv Builder option).
This step performs a pip install for about 6 libraries maintained externally. 
The problem I have is that this process takes time.

Is there a way of loading an image of the Python virtual environment? 
That way I could create another Jenkins job which generates this image, and this job would only be executed if there are significant changes to the libraries. And then my original automated test jobs will simply get the artifact from this external job at the start of the tests and load the virtual environment from there.

Comment: Why are these libraries slow to install? `pip install` compiles them from sources? Have you tried precompiled binary wheels?

Comment: You can work with docker. Create a docker image for your virtual environment and use the docker image in a pipeline in your current job. Just spin up the container, do your tests inside the container and bring it down again, instead of needing to install everything every time you can persist that configuration in your docker image/container.